# Installed canopy python gives floating point exception when running setup

Tags: python, linux, enthought, canopy

I've installed canopy python on a suse linux server and when trying to run the set up for command line use I get a floating point exception.  I get it just running the ~/Canopy/bin/_python, so it has something to do with the installation.  I have python2.4 and python2.6 already installed, but am installing canopy to get numpy with it.  Help!

Per helpful suggestions in the comments I've unset all the environment variables pertaining to other versions of python and still get the floating point exception when I run ~/Canopy/bin/_python as above.  Any thoughts?

I've removed all reference to python in my environment variables and reinstalled canopy and still get a floating point exception when trying to run the setup script.

The install did have these errors and warnings:

```
> [/home/NeuroCount/Canopy] >>>  Installing to /home/NeuroCount/Canopy
> ... please wait Must specify the vendor namespace for these files with
> --vendor No directories in update-desktop-database search path could be processed and updated.
> ***
> * Updating MIME database in /home/NeuroCount/.local/share/mime...
> * Error in type 'application/x-packagekit-plugin'
> *   (in /home/NeuroCount/.local/share/mime/packages/application-x-packagekit-plugin.xml):
> *   Unknown freedesktop.org field 'icon'.
> * Error in type 'application/x-skype'
> *   (in /home/NeuroCount/.local/share/mime/packages/application-x-skype.xml):
> *   Unknown freedesktop.org field 'icon'.
> * Warning: Unknown media type in type 'unknown/mime-type' Wrote 5 strings at 20 - 88 Wrote aliases at 88 - 8c Wrote parents at 8c - 90
> Wrote literal globs at 90 - 94 Wrote suffix globs at 94 - 1cc Wrote
> full globs at 1cc - 1d0 Wrote magic at 1d0 - 1dc Wrote namespace list
> at 1dc - 1e0
> *** done.
> 
>     You can run the Canopy graphical environment by running the script:
> 
>         /home/NeuroCount/Canopy/canopy
> 
>     or by selecting 'Canopy' in your Applications menu.
> 
>     On your first run, your Canopy User Python environment will be initialized,
>     and you will have the opportunity to make Canopy be your default Python
>     at the command line. Details at support.enthought.com/forums
> 
>     Thank you for installing Canopy!
```

but it's unclear to my feeble mind if this is fatal or show-stopping....

Anybody anywhere have any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that none of your environment variables refer to your other python installations.

Comment: Okay, I will do that.  Is there a quick and dirty way of making this my default python short of uninstalling the previous versions?

Comment: No need to uninstall anything. Just clean up your environment variables. For making it your default, see https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469730-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-

Comment: Are there any other environment variables besides PYTHONPATH that I should worry about?  I've unset that and still get the floating point exception.

Comment: PYTHONHOME is the worst. PATH could also be a factor. But check for yourself: `env | grep -i python`

Comment: PYTHONHOME is not set but PYTHONSTARTUP=/etc/pythonstart.  should I unset that?

Comment: That's unusual! Yes, please do unset it. Out of curiousity, what is in the file which it references? (Please put this info as an edit to your question, not in a comment.)